# Error starting a Java Process with ProcessBuilder in Jenkins on windows slave from unix

Tags: java, maven, hudson, jenkins, processbuilder

I have a unix machine running Jenkins master, and I have also configured a windows slave. That works nice. But when I run a groovy script using the groovy plugin (in option system groovy script), and use a java.lang.ProcessBuilder to run a maven command, I get this:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, 
    No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:148)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:65)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 122 more
Build step 'Groovy Postbuild' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

And the directory which the exception says doesn't exist, actually exists.

So my question is how can I start a maven command using [groovy script](https://mriet.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/groovy-jenkins-system-script/) on a windows slave when the master is running on a unix slave?

I find it speculative why I get the exception `java.lang.UNIXProcess` when I am running the groovy script on windows (the script file itself is located on the same machine as the windows slave, and I also checked from `System.getEnv()` that `JAVA_HOME` is correct)

Comment: are you sure your script is running on the slave and not on the master?  everything you say seems to indicate that your script is running on the unix master.

Comment: @jtahlborn the script starts with "C:/path/to/script/abc.groovy"